# Environment based page redirect

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect my website to a different site using the http-equiv="refresh" below is the code that I am using

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://abc.dev.com" />
```

Now I want it to be redirected to different URLs in different environment . Is there a way to set the URL as a variable that can be set in appsettings.json so that it can change for each environment?